# Why does the Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c) method require a Comparator object as it argument?

Tags: java, generics, collections, binary-search, comparator

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class MyComp implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
    
}
public class CollectionsAlgo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // Add elements to the array list.
        al.add("C");
        al.add("A");
        al.add("E");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("D");
        al.add("F");
        al.add(1, "A2");
        
        System.out.println("al: "+al);
        Collections.sort(al);
        System.out.println("al after sorting: "+al);
        int pos = Collections.binarySearch(al, "B", new MyComp());
        System.out.println("pos: "+pos);

    }

}
```

My question is what is the purpose of having a Comparator reference as parameter in the Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c) as we are already passing the list sorted in ascending order?

How could this Comparator reference help in doing the binary search?

Comment: Do you know how a binary search works?

Comment: You don't need a comparator when for string because string are already comparable.  So, use the first method which doesn't require a comparator.  If you have a custom class that does not implement comparable, you must provide a comparator so that the binary search algorithm knows how to compare the objects in the list.

Comment: The list is sorted, but `key` is not yet "sorted into" the list.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally, the binary search algorithm needs to know how to compare elements. When it examines a bisection point it needs to know if the element you're searching for is to the left or the right. That requires a comparison.

`Collections` has two `binarySearch` methods, [one with a comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T,java.util.Comparator)) and [one without](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T)). If your elements are `Comparable` then you don't need to pass a comparator. You can just pass the list and the search key:

```
int binarySearch​(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)
```

If they're not `Comparable` then you need to tell `binarySearch` how to compare them by passing a custom `Comparator`:

```
int binarySearch​(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

In your example code, `String`s are `Comparable`, so you don't need `MyComp`.

```
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(al, "B");
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that there are many different methods on Java's array class in order to use Binary Search. You can find a list of them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

In general, if you are searching for a primitive, byte, or comparable object in some array or list, you should be using one of the methods that doesn't include any comparator.

However, what if you have a list of objects that aren't comparable by default? For example, say you define a `Person` data type, which has some properties such as a height, and age, and a name. Now, say you are storing a list of persons. If you wanted to find a certain `Person` in a sorted list of `Person` objects, by default, Java has no idea how to perform this binary search.

As a reminder, Java determines where to move in the binary search by comparing the key it is currently inspecting to the target key. But, Java has no idea what it means to check whether one `Person` object is greater, less than, or equal to another. Should it use the height to determine which is greater? Should it compare based on last name or any other variable?

This is where comparators come in. I need to tell Java what it means when I ask to compare two `Person` objects.

To write the comparator, you need to create a class. This can be a private class in the same file as the object, or you can even write it in the method itself. The comparator should implement two methods: `compare` and `equals`. You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Once you write this, you pass in the comparator you just created, so Java now knows how to compare the objects in the given list or array.

Comment: Thanks dannyf325 and John Kugelman for your explanations. I now understand better why Comparator instance is required for binary search. It will be useful when the objects to be compared don't implement the Comparable interface so natural ordering won't be possible that's when we use that overloaded binarySearch() which accepts a Comparator instance.

Comment: Another not so obvious question is why the parameter declaration for Comparator instance in binarySearch() is like Comparator<? super T> c . I know that Comparator is a generic type  and ? is a wild card argument and "? super T" means the type parameter for Comparator must be a type which is supertype of T. The point I don't understand is why is it so? Why can't the parameter declaration for Comparator be just Comparator<T>?

Answer (score 0):

There are two sets of sort() and binarySearch(). They must be matched since binarySearch() must take a sorted list in ascending order.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)
```

Methods require  your T extends Comparable<? super T>. You are sorting and searching using your implmenation of Comparable. No need to set Comparator.

Javadoc for binarySearch:

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural
> ordering of its elements (as by the **sort(List)** method) prior to making
> this call.

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

None of methods require your T extends Comparable<? super T>. Even if you have implemented Comparable, you now have the option to choose as a different Comparator to sort and search.

Javadoc for binarySearch:

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the
> specified comparator (as by the **sort(List, Comparator)** method), prior
> to making this call.

```
record Person(String name, String address) implements Comparable<Person>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
public class binary_sorted_object {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> t = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Person("a", "400 Line"),
                new Person("c", "100 Line"),
                new Person("b", "800 Line")));

        Collections.sort(t);
        //sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method)
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(t, new Person("a", "400 Line")));

        Collections.sort(t, Comparator.comparing(Person::address));
        //Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator
        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(t,  new Person("a", "400 Line"), Comparator.comparing(Person::address)));
    }
}
```